# No incluye un jar del JRE (JDK1.7) en el Build Path en eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

En un proyecto en eclipse tengo configurado en el BuildPath el JDK1.7 (su JRE). En esa ruta veo que se encuentran todos estos JARs:

[image: Jars en la ruta del JRE]

Ahora bien, por un cambio reciente se han empezado a usar clases que se encuentran en el jar que he marcado, y al actualizar el proyecto, se producen errores de compilación en la clase javafx.util.Pair.

Veo que el problema es que en el Build Path del eclipse no aparecen todos los jars disponibles en la ruta del JRE:

[image: Jars del JDK1.7 en el BuildPath del Eclipse]

¿Por qué puede ser esto? Como solución temporal he añadido directamente en el proyecto el jar ausente (jfxrt.jar), pero debería cogerlo del JDK.

Comment: Creo recordar que JavaFX no es parte 'basica' del jdk en si por lo que por eso no te lo carga. De hecho en versiones anteriores de java creo que ni estaba incluido en el jdk.

Comment: ¿Y eso explica que no lo incluya el eclipse? Se está especificando la ruta del JDK... Por lógica deberían incluirse todos los jars que estuvieran allí. Aunque igual internamente en eclipse cada JDK tiene su relación de jars asociados, y por eso no se incluyen todos (estoy haciendo una suposición sin mucho fundamento, pero podría ser)...

Comment: No, Eclipse solo carga los que necesita, no todos.